# Unselected vertices and edges move along wth selected ones

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I'm pretty new to Blender, but I am stuck on one thing: every time I try to move a particular vertex, or edge loop, or whatever, using the Translation Widget or the "G" key, a number of other vertices and edges move as well, as if the rest of the object is reshaping as well.  However, I want to simply move the vertices or edges that I have selected, while keeping all other vertices fixed.  How could I do that?

Comment: Make sure Proportional Editing is turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you've turned on proportional editing.

To turn it off press the <kbd>O</kbd> key.

Or use the proportional editing icon on the bottom of the screen:

[image]

Follow [this link](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html?highlight=proportional) for more information on proportional editing