# After Shift D, original object wrongly move with the copy

Tags: modeling, transforms

I did the below.

1. Shift D ( Duplicate )
2. ESC ( cancel Grab )
3. Move object by Maniplator

At 3, not only the copy but also the original object moves.
But I want the original object to stay the original position before duplication.

Please see this gif and .blend file if necessary.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqalP.jpg
- https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/774983/shift-d-move.blend

Could you tell me how to avoid this problem?

Comment: Possibly caused by [proportional editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56878/30849).

Comment: I disabled Proportional editing and solved the problem.

Thanks for your help and I apologize for asking a question which has been answered.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.se. Don't worry, [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) are part of this sites mechanics.

Comment: I was relieved to read the blog whose URL you provided.
Thanks for your kindness !